# if taglib comparing with two items of forEach jstl

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, taglib

I have an forEach taglib inside another one. I would like to compare one attribute of each object being listed in its respective taglib.

```
<c:forEach items="${andares}" var="andar">

        ..........

        <c:forEach items="${lojas}" var="loja">
            <c:if test="${loja.andar == andar.numero}">
                     .....
            </c:if>      
        </c:forEach>

    </c:forEach>
```

I would like to only execute some code when the attribute "numero" of object andar is equals to attribute "andar" of object loja.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recall, but it seems like that should work. If not, perhaps this?

```
<c:forEach items="${andares}" var="andar">
    <c:set var="andarval" value="${anar.numero}"/>
    ..........
    <c:forEach items="${lojas}" var="loja">
        <c:set var="lojaval" value="${loja.andar}"/>
        <c:if test="${lojaval == andarval}">
        ....
        </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```